# How to get an element under a display:none div using htmlunit

Tags: java, xpath, htmlunit

Using HtmlUnit, How should I grab an element that is under a hidden div (style= "display:none")?

In this case, I am trying to get the value of a field presented in a table. the first cell is the field name and the second one is the value. I am using "for" attribute to find the associated value.

**HTML:**

```
<div style="display: none;" id="tab-doc-div">
<div class="tab-container" align="center">
    <table class="datatable">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th rowspan="1" colspan="1">
                    &nbsp;<label for="doc.change.stat">
                    <font color="">*&nbsp;</font>Action</label>
                </th>
                <td colspan="2">
                    Data Change (DTA)
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

**Java/HtmlUnit Code I'm using:**

```
public static String getTextForProperty(HtmlPage page, String property) throws Exception {
    List<HtmlLabel> labels = (List<HtmlLabel>)page.getByXPath("//label[@for='" + property + "']");

    if (labels.isEmpty()) {
        return null;
    } else {
        return labels.get(0).getParentNode().getNextSibling().asText();
    }
}
String myValue = getTextForProperty(myPageObject, "doc.change.stat"); //returns null
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your sample HTML file and your comment on the other answer:

> In my example I want to get the "Data Change (DTA)" as the result

This is all you need:

```
HtmlTableCell td = page.<HtmlTableCell>
                     getFirstByXPath("//label[@for='doc.change.stat']/../../td");
System.out.println(td.getTextContent().trim());
```

Comment: Thanks, That worked! The point is in using getTextContent() instead of doing asText().

Answer (score 0):

I would use getAttribute(String attributeName) http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/html/DomElement.html#getAttribute(java.lang.String)

Example :

```
for (HtmlLabel label : labels) {
if (!label.getAttribute("for").isEmpty()) {
myValue = label.getAttribute("for");
}
```

Comment: Maybe I was not clear enough. In my example I want to get the "Data Change (DTA)" as the result.

Comment: My bad, i did read too fast. By the way, the fact that it's under a hidden div, is no matter, it parses nodes. For your problem, just use `return labels.get(0).getParentNode().getNextSibling().getNextSibling().asText();`

Comment: Being under a hidden div does matter. try looking at the result of doing a foo.asText() on a page with some hidden stuff, they won't show up.

Comment: disagree, we can parse it. Try it on your html example : `page.getElementById("tab-doc-div").asText();` or 
  `((HtmlElement)page.getByXPath("//*[@id='tab-doc-div']/div/table/tbody/tr/td").get(0)).asText(); `